# Cannot create a compilation in Roslyn from source code

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

For test purposes, I need to get a `System.Reflection.Assembly` from a string `source` which contains a source code. I am using Roslyn:

```
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("TestCompilation", new[] { tree });

Assembly assembly = null;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var emitResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
    if (!emitResult.Success)
    {
        var message = emitResult.Diagnostics.Select(d => d.ToString())
            .Aggregate((d1, d2) => $"{d1}{Environment.NewLine}{d2}");

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Errors!{Environment.NewLine}{message}");
    }

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    assembly = Assembly.Load(stream.ToArray());
}
```

As you can see my attempt here is to emit a `CSHarpCompilation` object so that I can get the `Assembly` later. I am trying to do this with:

```
var source = @"
  namespace Root.MyNamespace1 {
    public class MyClass {
    }
  }
";
```

### Emit errors

But I fail at `var emitResult = compilation.Emit(stream)` and enter the conditional which shows the error. I get 1 warning and 3 errors:

- Warning CS8021: No value for RuntimeMetadataVersion found. No assembly containing System.Object was found nor was a value for RuntimeMetadataVersion specified through options.
- (3,34): Error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
- (3,34): Error CS1729: 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
- Error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

So it seems I need to add reference to `mscorelib` and it also seems like I need to tell Roslyn that I want to emit a class library, not an executable assembly. How to do that?

Comment: so convert the source string to c# code dynamically and then query the namespaces's..

Comment: For the part about a lack of referencing `mscorlib` this may be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992566/253938

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a metadata reference to `mscorlib` and you can change the compilation options via `CSharpCompilationOptions`.

Create your compilation as follows:

```
var Mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("TestCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib }, options: options);
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a **netstandard lib from *not-netstandard code*** (in my case I create a netstandard lib from core3.1) the code should be

```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("TestCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { 
        tree 
    }, 
    references: new[] { 
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll" 
    }, 
    options: 
        new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
```

A crux here is the path.
As the host code is core3.1 one cannot use `MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)` as it references a core3.1 `object` and not a netcore2.0 `object`.
As referencing a nuget package (nowadays) downloads them to the `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages` folder it can be loaded from there. This does not hold for any other user though so a different solution must be designed. One could utilise [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1) but that probably won't hold for CI/CD.

**Update**:
`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)` does hold for CI/CD.

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile( Path.Combine(
    UserProfilePath, ".nuget", "packages", "netstandard.library", "2.0.3", "build", 
    "netstandard2.0", "ref", "netstandard.dll"))
```

See [LehmanLaidun](https://github.com/LosManos/LehmanLaidun/actions) builds.