# Build project with Microsoft.Build API

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild

I'm trying to build a project using the classes in Microsoft.Build.

The code is:

```
var project = new ProjectInstance(CS_PROJ_FILE);
project.Build();
```

However it's throwing the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Type information for Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper was present in the whitelist cache as Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a but the type could not be loaded. unexpectedly null
  Source=Microsoft.Build
```

I've tried adding the following to the packages (both in a net452 and a net7 project):

- id="Microsoft.Build" version="15.1.1012"
- id="Microsoft.Build.Framework" version="15.1.1012"
- id="Microsoft.Build.Runtime" version="15.1.1012"
- id="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" version="15.1.1012"
- id="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" version="15.1.1012"

Still get the same result.

I've also tried using the `BuildManager` like this:

```
var buildManager = new BuildManager();
buildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(),
                   new BuildRequestData(new ProjectInstance(CS_PROJ_FILE), 
                                        new[] {"Build"}));
```

Answer (score 22):

I hit the same error after I installed:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Build -Version 15.1.1012
```

But then I installed:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core -Version 15.1.1012
```

And things started working.

A little confusing...

I was pointed to this stackoverflow question by "dasMulli" at:

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1889

Comment: Odd. I'll try again with a clean project.

Answer (score 7):

There is apparently a new way to fix this problem, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886334/253938) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26029).

Here's what worked for me:

1. I deleted `Microsoft.Build.dll`, `Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll`, `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll` and `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll` (i.e., all `Microsoft.Build` .dll files) from my project's output folder.
2. I deleted several `Microsoft.Build` NuGet packages from my project's references.
3. I installed the `Microsoft.Build.Locator` NuGet package for my project.
4. I added the following code to my program:

   ```
    // This needed after upgrading to Roslyn revision 34025, see these two links:
    //  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26029
    //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886334/253938
    MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
   ```

This fixed the exception listed by the OP *and* avoided the tons of compiler error messages about being unable to resolve all references.

Edit: More information here: https://gist.github.com/DustinCampbell/32cd69d04ea1c08a16ae5c4cd21dd3a3

Comment: This also answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821851/main-method-not-found-when-compiling-through-roslyn)

Answer (score 2):

Micrsoft provides a good link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/updating-an-existing-application?view=vs-2017#use-microsoftbuildlocator)

The trick is indeed to use nuget pacakges, and to specify ExcludeAssets=runtime to tell NuGet that the assemblies are needed only at build time, and shouldn't be copied to the output directory.