# 'Main' method not found when compiling through Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to compile a solution with run-time generated code. While the solution compiles perfectly when opened from Visual Studio, it fails from Roslyn:

> error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
>   for an entry point

The solution I am trying to compile has a single ASP.NET Core 2 (.NET Framework 4.6.2) project, which of course has a Main method in the Program class at the root of the project:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm running to compile that solution, from a .NET 4.7 WPF application:

```
private static async Task<bool> CompileSolution(string solutionPath, string outputDir)
{
    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    var projectCompilation = await solution.Projects.Single().GetCompilationAsync();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectCompilation?.AssemblyName))
    {
        return false;
    }

    using (var stream = File.Create(Path.Combine(outputDir, $"{projectCompilation.AssemblyName}.dll")))
    {
        var result = projectCompilation.Emit(stream);
        return result.Success;
    }
}
```

`projectCompilation.Emit` fails with:

> - warning CS8021: No value for RuntimeMetadataVersion found. No assembly containing System.Object was found nor was a value for
>     RuntimeMetadataVersion specified through options.
> - error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
>     for an entry point

Could it be that the NuGet package being used does not correctly support .NET Core 2 projects yet? I do not have any pending (not even preview) package updates.

I have now updated the ASP.NET Core project to .NET 4.7, so that the version is the same on both solutions, but didn't change the error generated. The csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject>Practia.CrudGenerator.Web.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>..NUGET PACKAGES...</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please add the class definition that contains your `Main` method.

Comment: @ErikPhilips updated. It's the standard VS generated project

Comment: Have you [taken a look at this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577298/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point)

Comment: @ErikPhilips tried everything there, nothing changed any of the messages the Emit generates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding these two lines before attempting to emit the result:

```
compilation = compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
compilation = compilation.WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
```

Notice that both `AddReferences` and `WithOptions` return new `Compilation` instances, so it is necessary to re-assign.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992566/253938 for a possible way to avoid having to add a reference for `mscorlib` and avoiding some other problems involving `MSBuildWorkspace`.

Comment: @RenniePet I add the exact problem of this question and your link solved perfectly without manual tweaks. Please, take credit to add another answer here (which I will upvote) with references to your linked answer. Your solution for this question is much more general and correct and should be pointed out clearly, not in a comment.

Comment: @ceztko Thanks for your suggestion, but I'll just stick with providing a link to my answer on the other thread.

Comment: @RenniePet as you wish, I already upvoted even that. You could potentially capitalize better scoring adding another answer here (just with link) because, as said, your solution is way more general

Comment: @ceztko Copying answers is against SO rules, please do not suggest that.

Comment: @Camilo I really prefer talking about quality than rules. RenniePet answer in another question is the best answer to your own question here. How you deal with that? Are you so certain that by SO rules he can't link himself on another SO answer?

Comment: @ceztko Yes, I'm completely certain. And what he answered has nothing to do with this question. Besides, look at the date, this is way too old

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well, sorry to say I disagree with that. In my opinion your question is truly fully answered by RenniePet answer: your solution may work for limited cases and fail for many others because it's clear that `MSBuildWorkspace` is missing much context initialization.

Comment: @ceztko And that's ok. I am not on that project anymore so I cannot test and tell you you are right. What RenniePet answer may or may not have worked, the problem is completely different (I never missed a `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core`)