# Roslyn-compiled project generates empty assembly

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45821851/3932049) where I already got the solution via a combination of a couple dozens of posts.

This can be reproduced easily:

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="15.3.409" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" Version="15.3.409" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="2.3.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" Version="1.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            var project = workspace.OpenProjectAsyn(@"C:\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj").Result;
            var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var result = compilation.Emit(memoryStream);
                if (result.Success)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"C:\WebApplication1\", $"{compilation.AssemblyName}.dll"), memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the Worskpace after loading the solution, I have an error message on the Diagnostics property:

```
Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj' with message: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
```

Comment: Right... then I'm skeptical that actually "solved" your problem, rather than just allowing you to go on. :-) You could try groveling around in `solution.Projects` in the debugger to see if anything looks obviously off. That's just spitballing; I have no personal experience with the Roslyn API.

Comment: which version of the roslyn nuget package are you using?

Comment: @m0sa if you refer to the Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package, it's 2.3.1

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets here and there.

Comment: @JonSkeet in this [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21660) I provided the steps to reproduce quite easily. Unfortunately, since they are two different solutions, it's not really possible to do it on SO. Would it work if I uploaded the MCVE to GitHub?

Comment: I don't see why it's "not really possible to do it on SO". It's fine to have two pieces of code that make up the [mcve]. But I would try to really reduce it to be minimal - does it *have* to be an ASP.NET Core application that you're compiling to demonstrate the problem? Would a simple class library or console app with no dependencies demonstrate it too? (If not, that's interesting in itself - and may well be the cause of your "update".) Even if it does need to be an ASP.NET Core project, you could minimize that too, to just the absolute barest bones required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Whether you're interested in other project types is irrelevant to the diagnostics aspect. You should do as much diagnostic work as possible *before* asking a question. Furthermore, your examples are incomplete -  you've made it take a lot more work than necessary in order to reproduce. *Complete* code should be copy/paste/compile/runnable - a complete project file and complete code really doesn't have to be very large.

Comment: Basically, if you can't be bothered to put effort into making it as easy as possible for people to help you, you should expect that at least some people (myself included) won't be bothered to put the effort into helping you.

Comment: Next, is a solution file actually required? What about just a project file, with no solution?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've included the entire .csproj and .sln files. I'm not sure if it's needed, but it could be something regarding how VS is creating the .sln file.

Comment: That's *still* not the whole cs file though - and is this now all in one application, i.e. trying to compile itself? Or is there other code that's missing?

Comment: @JonSkeet On the real world use-case, the ASP.NET Core application is on one solution and the code compiling the ASP.NET Core application is on another solution. I joined these together trying to  provide the most minimal example possible. The error message is the same, so it doesn't seem it changes anything. The posted example is now the full code

Comment: Right, that definitely helps. So the next thing to check, as requested, is whether you need the solution file at all. If you just add the project file, do you get the same problem? (I strongly suspect the problem is that the project file is for the Web SDK and you need to somehow say where to find that, but we can check that when we've got down to a minimal example...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Loading directly the `.csproj` and using `workspace.OpenProjectAsync` results in the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @DustinCampbell [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21660), this not a supported scenario yet.

I solved this by instead calling `dotnet build` from a `Process`.